# How to speed up `kubernetes.yml` Quarkus generation

Tags: maven, quarkus

As per [Deploying to Kubernetes](https://es.quarkus.io/version/2.7/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes) one can generate `kubernetes.yml` by executing `./mvnw clean package`, which also happens to do additional things.

Is it possible to generate only `kubernetes.yml` without building the `.jar` file, or is it necessary for the generation?

Comment: This is currently not possible, but you can certainly request the feature on our Github issue tracker.

Comment: For future reference: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/37468